# Give record access to community user whose email address matches that of a custom field

Tags: customer-community, community-builder

I am currently building out a closed customer community which will enable contractual employees (external to our sf org) to read-only records of a custom object (Market_Project__c) for which they are the noted as the supervisor by connecting their contact record email to a custom field on the Market Project (Confirmed_Supervisor_Email__c)[this is done via lookup field to a related opportunity].  I do not want any community members to be able to see any info for events that they are not marked as supervisor for.

In previous attempts, I used a visual flow embedded on a vf page overriding a tab to look up via `{!Market_Project__c.Confirmed_Supervisor_Email__c}` on `{!User.Email}`, but I would really like to utilize one of the more attractive community templates- disabling my ability to use visualforce.

I am not terribly experienced with SFDC or programming, but if somebody could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic!

**Edit**

I feel like I may be on the right track here- will the criteria below be sufficient for what I am looking to do?

[image: sharing rule]